# How to pre-resolve conflicts in git, so they will disappear in an actual merge?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a master-branch. Also I have a feature-branch, which conflicts with a master-branch. Is there a way to apply some changes to the feature-branch only, such that the attempt to merge feature-branch via git command won't produce any conflicts, except the conflicts that I can automatically resolve by using `ours` or `theirs` strategy?

I exclude the variants, where I lose the featured changes in the feature-branch - like, replacing it with master-branch, etc.

Also I have some prerequisites on a branch before merging it in master - like, compilation, unit-tests, etc. So the suggested changes should not break the prerequisites.

Is it possible in theory for every kind of conflict?

Comment: if I understand, you want to merge from master to feature branch, losing changes made in feature in case of conflics (and keeping master's code)?

Comment: No, I want the opposite - by "I exclude the variants", I mean that I don't want such variants to be listed as answers - since they are trivial and meaningless.

Comment: So, in your case, you does commit to both master and feature during development, later during release you want to have feature merged to master ?

Comment: @JeslyVarghese Yes, this can be the case. If I do not commit anything to master, there will be no conflicts with merge, I suggest. But your terms are confusing - the "development" and "release" mean some concrete workflow.

Comment: yup, the best practice is to leave master away from any active commits while development. have a separate development branch to have your releases merged. Read [this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). If you are having active commits in both master and release (almost parallel) then there is no way to escape from conflicts while merging.

Comment: And isn't theirs, your conflict resolution style is for svn? I am not aware how git ui tools does this.

Comment: It's a good article, but I can't change my workflow. Also, I don't want to avoid conflicts at all - I want to pre-resolve most of them. That is the point of the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33749/discussion-between-jesly-varghese-and-abyss-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is actually very easy and a very common thing to do in git: I assume you have a workflow in which `master` is maintained by a single person, but multiple people develop feature branches?

You just require the maintainers of the feature branch to merge `master` into their branch before they proclaim their branch “done”. That guarantees conflict-free merging “right now”. If you merge something else first, you might have to ask the maintainer to merge again, though.

Sidenote: you should almost never use ours or theirs merge strategy, unless you *really* know what you are doing.

Comment: Should it work out because of the new common ancestor, or because of the changes in the code?

Comment: It will work due to the common ancestor. That will make the feature merge into master a fast-forward.

Comment: The common ancestor is why this works from git’s point of view. But the fact that the common ancestor exists is also clear proof that the code changes happened. At least that’s how git sees it. So the full answer is: both. While you can of course create this common ancestor without code changes, you will be lying to git. So git’s assumption breaks and with it the base for its algorithms.

Comment: Should it work without common ancestor? For example, if I `git merge --squash master` ?

Comment: Sometimes it might, sometimes it might not. You will probably cause more merge conflicts than without that merging at all. Why would you want to do something like that?